What can cause these CAN signal distortions?
I occasionally observe signal distortions on CAN H, CAN L, and so also the differential signal. It is causing the microcontroller (dsPIC33) to report so-called Invalid Message Receive (IVR) errors. This error is triggered by
Bit Error, Acknowledge Error, Form Error, Stuffing Error or CRC Error. Finally, CAN frames fail and the system stops on command response errors.
The system is like a 3D printer. Each CAN node is motorized and moves independently from each other. Baudrate is 125 kbps. Total bus length is 2 mtr but there are 8 interconnection PCBs. The pinned connectors are not soldered. Cable is a Nicomatic foil because of the moving nodes. The foil also carries 48V and GND. It is not twisted and is designed for motions.
It is not happening on all systems, and it happens infrequently. This makes it hard finding the cause of the distortions.
Any idea on what can cause the distortions? Thank you!



What's the signal pin-out in the cable like? Are you using the supply ground as reference for CAN? Are there large ground currents from those motors on that same ground? Check out What are the most common causes of CAN bus communication errors?, the part about ground potentials in particular.

The scope diagram shows that the GND potential difference between the nodes is too large.
The 'Nicomatic foil' may not be suitable for power distribution. Or it could be a loose connection (you said the errors only occur sporadically).
To check this, you could wire beefy power lines and see if the communication errors disappear.

Also, verify that the CAN bus is terminated on both ends.
